# What stops Firefox from rendering a page 

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm currently facing the problem that the server delivers a page with valid xhtml (transitional) but Firefox (3.x) refuses to render it every now and then. Reloading the page (F5) shows the rendered contents as supposed.

Looking it up in Firebug shows that the server delivered everything and that the html-header als "arrived" ... but it seems that the  doesn't have any contents - also not even the onload-event is triggered (if something is defined there) - so it seems that Firefox never really "tries" to process the .

Several others also reported this issue, therefore I assume that it's not a local bug.

Are there any known issues in regards to Firefox which could be related somehow?

Comment: We need a lot more information.

Comment: I've seen this too and assumed its a FF bug because its not site dependent in my case

Comment: Could use more information. Perhaps a problem with your mime-types on the server (is it an actual .htm/.html file) or is it a script that outputs xhtml. I know that FF is very picky on mime-types.

Comment: @Zyphrax: you mean the difference between HTML sent as `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`? Or other mime-types causing problems?

Comment: @Marcel: yes or even text/xml or similar. Have a look at the mime-type in your response (you should be able to see this in the page properties of FF). Just a thought, but it could be a million things, need more info :)

Comment: Well my real usecase is a script which is part of the TYPO3 backend .. text/html ... any idea?

Comment: Besides the mime-type sometimes if the file is UTF-8 encoded but saved in UTF-8 with BOM format, it can be rendered incorrectly or not rendered.

Comment: I've experienced this before, and only in Firefox - sometimes it renders nothing as you said, sometimes it renders the HTML but none or some of the CSS. I think it's an application-level bug and not something you can change with your markup!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its dynamic js caused it.

```
$.getScript('http://v2.jiathis.com/code/jia.js', function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

The code above will stop Firefox 3.x from rendering.